# How to use i18n variables in Pug template files?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, pug

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to learn how to use [i18n](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) in my Pug template and could not find my answer anywhere.

The documentation says

> in your templates (depending on your template engine)

```
<%= __('Hello') %>

${__('Hello')}
```

So far I tried (in my pug template)

```
${__('Hello')}

__('Hello')
```

None of those syntax is working, what is the correct one to use ?

I know it is well configure because when using

```
i18n.__('Hello')
```

And sending it to my template in a variable it is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer was right in the documentation, only needed to add this to my configuration.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // express helper for natively supported engines
    res.locals.__ = res.__ = function() {
        return i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
    };

    next();
});
```

Comment: What is 'arguments' here?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Sam's answer, bear in mind you should use `#{__('Hello')}` template syntax to use this i18n helper.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to npm i new one and register global as below. Then you can use `__('Hello')`.

```
const i18n = require("i18n");

app.use(i18n.init);
i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'de', 'vi'],
    directory: './locales',
    register: global
});
i18n.setLocale('vi');
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is useful. Just like to share. I encountered the same problem where i can see the translated text using req.i18n.__() but cannot see in the pug using i18n-2. How I solved is:
1. make sure the i18n config is after the app.use(cookieParser());

```
// add i18n config after app used the cookieParser
var i18n = require('i18n-2');

// Attach the i18n property to the express request object
// And attach helper methods for use in templates
i18n.expressBind(app, {
    // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
    locales: ['en', 'zh'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    // change the cookie name from 'lang' to 'locale'
    cookieName: 'locale'
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
  next();
});
```

2. Make sure the following template setting is placed after the above i18n config.

   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
   app.set('view engine', 'pug');
3. In pug, use syntax like: #{__('Login')}